# Is Tarvek believing Gil to be descended from pirates canon?

Tags: girl-genius

So, I read a decent amount of [Girl Genius](http://girlgeniusonline.com) fanfiction. And the lines blur pretty readily since the Foglios have leaked a lot of details about the backstory to fans that haven't reached the current comic canon. On the other hand, I've also read the novelizations, which include additional detail.

Recently, I was considering Tarvek's knowledge of Gil's ancestry. I know that comic canon has them finding out (falsely) that Gil's father was the Spark of legend who create a sausage-making machine that took him out, and that finding that out was where [Tarvek and Gil had a split due to Tarvek not believing it, and swearing to know more, and Gil confessing to the location of Tarvek's spy reports](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20090916#.Whr9hLgtVYM), leading to him getting expelled from Castle Wulfenbach. But I have this vivid memory of Tarvek later discovering that Gil was the son of a pirate, that being why his background was a mystery, and I can't remember if that was canonical (for all that the true background of Gil is, of course, as the Baron's son) that he'd found this second "truth" and believed in it.

So, long story short, is it canonical that, after being expelled, Tarvek was convinced Gil was descended from pirates?

Comment: GIl's piracy: http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20090220 :D

Comment: @Mithoron: OK, so that's where Gil states that background to Zola. But was there a situation where Tarvek, having tried to delve deeper into Gil's background as per his stated intention after they learned the first false backstory, instead found the Pirate background?

Comment: Another interesting part is not Gil's father, but his mother, and why Zeetha would kill him on sight if she knew.  I think Gil's mother is Skifandrian.  I have also wondered for sometime if the Heterodyne brothers are on Mars, or if Zeetha comes from there.

Comment: @EngrStudent: That's the consistent fan theory, that the Baron is the famed Chump, with his disappearance after Lucrezia drugged him being the result of him being dumped in a portal much like the one mentioned in the Heterodyne story with Doctor Mongfish and the wasps.

Comment: I was looking at their ability to predict the slavers aerodynamics.  To me it seemed stellar/planetary-astrophysics.  Also Mars is relatively close every 15 or 17 years.  Absolute closest is every 284 years.

Comment: @EngrStudent What is it with this literal reading of this dragon story? This "Mars" is most probably equivalent of the Geister's dimension. No idea why you went to this topic though, so don't continue it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Och, and the answer was closer than I thought. Right after the strip where [Tarvek vows to learn more](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20090916), the next strip explains him mistakenly believing Gil to be "[the son of Petrus Teufel, leader of the Black Mist Raiders](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20090918)", which is pretty close to Gil's later lie to Zola that [he is a pirate](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20090220), which I may have conflated. He [didn't realize the truth until Castle Heterodyne](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20090921) and it was still later that he realized that [the reason Gil turned on him was because Gil had learned he was the Baron's son](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20120217).

Comment: Yeah, I was searching for this strip, but had too short attention span :D That was pretty good disinformation and interesting thing about the world of GG.